# how to get/set TestStep's property value using javascript in soapUI?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, soapui

i have tried using Groovy script.
the following code is to set property value using roovy script:

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases[testCaseName].testSteps[testStepName].setPropertyValue("request",object);
```

"request" is a property of testStep.
object is a some value.

when i try above code in javascript but i got following error:

org.mozilla.javascript.ecmaerror: TypeErro: org.mozilla.javascript.ecmaerror Cannot read property "testSteps" from undefined.

So please tell me how to use in using javascript?

Comment: do you try to set a property in another testcase ?

Comment: yes, i tried many other testcases.

Comment: try this: def ts = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getTestCaseByName("testcasename")
ts.setPropertyValue("abc","bcd"). by the way, testCases have properties, testsuites as well but testSteps don't

Comment: hey, i want for javascript. i think above is for groovy.

Comment: you're right ... sorry

Comment: i have posted below answer. please see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hurra, i got solution. Please see following code:

```
var project = testRunner.getTestCase().getTestSuite().getProject();
var testSuite = project.getTestSuiteByName("TestSuite");
var testCasesItr=testSuite.getTestCaseList().iterator();
while(testCasesItr.hasNext())
{
        var testStepsItr = testCasesItr.getTestStepList().iterator();
        while(testStepsItr.hasNext()){
            var testStep = testStepsItr.next();
            log.info(testStep.getPropertyValue("response"));
              // here you can set property
              // testStep.setPropertyValue("request","someValue");

        }

}
```

above code will run for all the testcases.